# Обведение контура здания тапом

Tags: android, activity, google-maps-api, google-maps

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу выделить здание в Google Maps в своём приложении. Конкретно, я тапаю на здание, оно автоматически проводит линию по контуру данного здания. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что будет проводить линию красиво и с анимацией, но такая возможность [есть](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/?hl=ru) и официальна.

Вам нужно изучить **Импорт данных KML на карту**.

> Эта служебная программа позволяет преобразовывать объекты [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?hl=ru) в
>   географические фигуры и добавлять их в виде слоя поверх карты. Чтобы
>   добавить слой к карте, вызовите метод addLayerToMap(). Доступ к
>   свойствам объекта KML можно получить путем вызова метода
>   getProperties() для любого объекта Placemark, GroundOverlay, Document
>   или Folder. Дополнительные сведения см. в документации для служебной
>   программы [Google Maps Android KML.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml?hl=ru)

Пример от *Google* на [Github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/KmlDemoActivity.java)

> Примечание. В настоящее время эта служебная программа доступна в бета-версии. Чтобы сообщить о возникших проблемах или выявленных ошибках, воспользуйтесь системой отслеживания проблем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. В любом случае, есть куда копать