# Кастомзация карты Google Maps в приложении

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как на карте Google Maps выделять область и создавать свои маркеры по аналогии с рисунком? Есть ли где-то документация по поводу этого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выделение похоже на полигоны, а группировка маркеров это Marker Clustering

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737888/205563 + https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java